# How to prove an inequality for beginners

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am a beginner in proofs and, unfortunately, I cannot wrap my mind around how to prove the simplest things, so I need a bit of help getting started. This is the proof that I am dealing with:

$\text{If }x< y< 0\text{, then }x^{2}> y^{2}\text{.}$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One way: start with $\,x^2-y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)\,$ and note that both factors on the RHS are negative (*why?*). It follows that $x^2-y^2 \gt 0 \iff x^2 \gt y^2\,$.

Comment: You've put in the tag "real-analysis". Often a real analysis course begins with some axioms. Do you have any axioms that you're supposed to be working with? Do you have any theorems that you think might be useful?

Answer (score 2):

If $x < y < 0$ then $|x| > |y|$ so $$x^2 = |x|^2 > |y|^2 = y^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying an inequality by a negative number reverses the inequality.

---

We have $x<y$ and multiplying it with negative number $x$ we get $x^2>xy$. Again multiplying the same starting inequality by negative number $y$ we get $xy>y^2$. Now using $x^2>xy$ and $xy>y^2$ we arrive at $x^2>y^2$.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$x<y<0 \iff 0<-y<-x $$

and since $f(a)=a^2$ is strictly increasing for $a>0$

$$0<-y<-x \implies 0<(-y)^2<(-x)^2$$

that is

$$x^2>y^2>0$$

Answer (score 0):

$x^2>y^2\Rightarrow|x|>|y|\Rightarrow y>x$ for $x,y<0.$